# JHipster Entity Generator crahing

Tags: jhipster

I have my first JHIpster app running in Docker. Would now like to create an Entity.

Running

yo jhipster:entity event

gives the error below.

I dont know enough to even sart de-bugging? Can I refresh something?

```
jhipster@fbc619c7539d:~/app$ yo jhipster:entity event
? ==========================================================================
We're constantly looking for ways to make yo better!
May we anonymously report usage statistics to improve the tool over time?
More info: https://github.com/yeoman/insight & http://yeoman.io
========================================================================== (Y/n)

/usr/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/rx-lite/rx.lite.js:75
    throw e;
    ^

SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /.{1,0}/: numbers out of order in {} quantifier.
    at new RegExp (native)
    at breakLines (/usr/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/insight/node_modules/inquirer/lib/utils/screen-manager.js:108:15)
    at ScreenManager.render (/usr/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/insight/node_modules/inquirer/lib/utils/screen-manager.js:55:22)
    at Prompt.render (/usr/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/insight/node_modules/inquirer/lib/prompts/confirm.js:85:15)
    at Prompt._run (/usr/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/insight/node_modules/inquirer/lib/prompts/confirm.js:65:8)
    at Prompt.run (/usr/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/insight/node_modules/inquirer/lib/prompts/base.js:57:8)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/insight/node_modules/inquirer/lib/ui/prompt.js:84:12)
    at module.exports (/usr/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/run-async/index.js:15:21)
    at AnonymousObservable.__subscribe (/usr/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/insight/node_modules/inquirer/lib/utils/utils.js:16:7)
    at AnonymousObservable.tryCatcher (/usr/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/rx-lite/rx.lite.js:63:31)
```

Comment: Please give information about your environment running `yo jhipster:info`

Comment: yo jhipster:info gave me the same error. That says something was corrupted. So I re-installed from scratch and its working fine. Thanks for the tip Gael, it will help me in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this error implied some kind of corruption of JHipster and or node. Re-installing node and JHipster did not help me, but building a new Docker image worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Please delete jhipster and yo from your user and reinstall those from root. this will work 100% tasted too many times