# error docker jhipster version 4.0.2

Tags: docker, yeoman, jhipster, yeoman-generator

I've pulled jhipster docker version 4.0.2 and when I try to create a new proyect I get a error :

yo jhipster
We're constantly looking for ways to make yo better! 
May we anonymously report usage statistics to improve the tool over time? 
More info: https://github.com/yeoman/insight & http://yeoman.io
========================================================================== (Y/n)

/usr/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/rx-lite/rx.lite.js:75
    throw e;
    ^

SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /.{1,0}/: numbers out of order in {} quantifier
    at RegExp (native)
    at breakLines (/usr/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/insight/node_modules/inquirer/lib/utils/screen-manager.js:108:15)
    at ScreenManager.render (/usr/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/insight/node_modules/inquirer/lib/utils/screen-manager.js:55:22)
    at Prompt.render (/usr/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/insight/node_modules/inquirer/lib/prompts/confirm.js:85:15)
    at Prompt._run (/usr/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/insight/node_modules/inquirer/lib/prompts/confirm.js:65:8)
    at Prompt.run (/usr/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/insight/node_modules/inquirer/lib/prompts/base.js:57:8)
    at Object. (/usr/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/insight/node_modules/inquirer/lib/ui/prompt.js:84:12)
    at module.exports (/usr/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/run-async/index.js:15:21)
    at AnonymousObservable.__subscribe (/usr/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/insight/node_modules/inquirer/lib/utils/utils.js:16:7)
    at AnonymousObservable.tryCatcher (/usr/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/rx-lite/rx.lite.js:63:31)

Any idea?

Comment: It seems something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39915655/jhipster-entity-generator-crahing . Try building a new image from Dockerfile.

Comment: yo jhipster:info to give details about your environment